# Сelery (ImportError: cannot import name '_state')

Tags: django-rest-framework, celery, python-import, importerror

Win10 systems, imported the celery and eventlet module. I tried to add celery to my django project, wrote the init file in the settings folder and created the celery.py file. I specified all the necessary variables in the project settings. After running the project I get the following error:

```
 File "E:\PycharmProjects\DRF_homeworks\config\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\DRF_homeworks\config\celery.py", line 1, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\DRF_homeworks\venv\Lib\site-packages\celery\local.py", line 460, in __getattr__
    module = __import__(self._object_origins[name], None, None,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\DRF_homeworks\venv\Lib\site-packages\celery\app\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from config.celery import _state
ImportError: cannot import name '_state' from partially initialized module 'config.celery' (most likely due to a circular import) (E:\PycharmProjects\DRF_homeworks\config\celery.py)
```

[My celery error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO9VV.png)
Maybe, anyone have some idea about it?

I tried renaming:

- the file,
- the name of the celery application.

specifying the exact path to the file in the import.

Comment: Celery is not developed to work on Windows. If it does, that is a coincidence.

Comment: This is true. An eventlet module was created specifically for compatibility between window10 and celery and in another project everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something went wrong. Reinstalling the celery package helped. The question is closed.